# JavaFx 2 applicaton does not run when i run it through HTML page

Tags: html, firefox, javafx-2

I have downloaded the javafx 2 samples and want to run in from its HMTL. For example there is one javafx application called BrickBreaker. For the specific sample the following files exist :  BrickBreaker.jar, BrickBreaker.jnlp and BrickBreaker.html

When double clicking on jar or jnlp the application runs as expected but when i click on the html the application does not run. Instead i get the message "View the conectes of the page. Please install javaFX"

Why is that happening ? ( i have the javafx installed  as the application runs when choosing the jar and jnlp files). My guess is that the html should be called from within the context of a webserver meaning that i should deploy my application first to a server and call the url from my explorer. For example if using glassfish i  should call the url http://localhost:8080/Brickbraker 
The problem is that i don't know how to deploy the javafx application in the server. 
i tried to copy paste all the above three files in the autodeploy folder but it didnt worked...
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: some more info - I have installed JDK 7 and JavaFX SDK 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JavaFX is client technology, you don't need Glassfish to run it. JavaFX should run in browser the same way as Java plugins do.

If you can't run an application directly from html file it means your browser doesn't recognize you have runtime installed.

There can be next reasons for that:

- JavaFX runtime is actually not installed (check in Windows Control Panel)
- pure java plugin is not installed (you can check on java.com)
- javafx runtime is 32bit and you are using 64bit browser (or vice versa)
- you are using not supported browser (e.g. Safari)
- you are using not supported system (at this moment, January 2012, only Windows supports runtime)

Comment: Thanks for answering.. i checked one by one the list but nonoe of the bullets apply.
1) java FX is installed.. when i try to install the javaFX runtime i get the message that "it is already installed"
2)Java is indeed installed (java 7)
3) checked.. i have downloaded 64bit runtime (my pc is windows 7 64 bit)
4) im using Firefox
5) windows 7...
I will check the version of firefox and try to run in in IE.
Thanks

Comment: Firefox doesn't have 64bit version AFAIK, so that could be the reason

Comment: Yes.. that was it after all.
"javafx runtime is 32bit and you are using 64bit browser (or vice versa)"
 I tried the same with with JavaFX 2.0.2 32 bit and it worked fine!Thanks for your help